# AttributeError: '_hashlib.HASH' object has no attribute 'oid'

Tags: python, pyopenssl, pycryptodome

I am trying to create a script which verifies a signature using a public key.

The `payload-signature` input parameter has a format as follows:

```
t=1616635947,v=bhadkjl;fghklj;akdfnbkljnbkljfdnbklnbk
```

Where v is the timestamp when the signature is created and v is signature on the SHA512 hash of the string value of `t + "." + payload`. For example `1616635947.{randomdataqwertyuiop}`

When I run my script I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    result = verify_signature(x_payload_signature, public_key, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 26, in verify_signature
    pkcs1_15.new(rsa_key).verify(h, signature)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Signature\pkcs1_15.py", line 120, in verify
    possible_em1 = [ _EMSA_PKCS1_V1_5_ENCODE(msg_hash, k, True) ]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Signature\pkcs1_15.py", line 191, in _EMSA_PKCS1_V1_5_ENCODE
    digestAlgo = DerSequence([ DerObjectId(msg_hash.oid).encode() ])
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_hashlib.HASH' object has no attribute 'oid'
```

Here is my code for reference

```
import base64
from hashlib import sha512
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15


def verify_signature(payload_signature: str, pub_key: str, payload: str):
    # create public key
    key_der = base64.b64decode(pub_key)
    rsa_key = RSA.importKey(key_der)

    # split payload signature into timestamp and signature
    parts = payload_signature.split(",")
    timestamp = parts[0].split("=")[1]
    sig_to_verify = parts[1][2:]

    # Update signature object with 'timestamp.payload'
    v = timestamp + "." + payload
    message = v.encode("utf-8")

    # Verify signature
    signature = base64.b64decode(sig_to_verify)
    h = sha512(message)

    try:
        pkcs1_15.new(rsa_key).verify(h, signature)
        print("The signature is valid.")
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("The signature is not valid.")
```